# How to connect Octave to Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, octave, ojdbc

Can't find a way to connect Octave (running on Windows 10) to Oracle DB. I would like to code an SQL select-query directly in Octave command line and get data retrieved in Octave from Oracle DB.

I am new at Octave. Tried to find the answer at Stack and in several Octave tutorials, but not succeeded.

For now I am able to do it in R rather than in Octave, and it would be something like this:

```
library(RJDBC)
library(rJava)
driver <- JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", [Oracle driver path])
con <- dbConnect(drv = driver, [connection to server], [schema], [password])
data <- dbGetQuery(con, [SQL select-query])
```

Comment: Use it the same way: you can use Java from within Octave

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I would love to know: what's "the same way" in this case?

Comment: Please add your solution and mark it as answer. As far as I can read from your other question you solved it yourself

Comment: I will, Andy. My solution is not yet completed, I miss the last part of it, which is lthe line: data<-dbGetQuery(con, [SQL select-query]). In R I can read directly from that "data" object. In Octave I end up with a ResultSet which I can't read so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Octave does not have support for connecting to Oracle.

Because Octave supports embedded Java, you could code this up yourself using Java and JDBC. But doing that in a way that has good performance is a big project, because the Octave/Java external interface layer is kind of slow, and JDBC has inherent inefficiencies that show up particularly in regards to how the Octave/Java interface works.

Instead, I'd suggest that you write a small program in Python/NumPy, R, or another language that you're comfortable with and has official support for Octave connectivity and can generate Octave-compatible MAT files (or some other data format you're comfortable working with). Have that program take a SQL query as input and generate a MAT file containing the result set as output. Call out to that program from your Octave program, and get the results by reading in the MAT file.